# CWAC LocationPoller - Broadcast not being received

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I was linked to your library (once again, THANKS and excellent work).

I've been trying for the past two hours what the problem is but I've failed.

Here's the AlarmManager in my Login screen code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(con, LocationPoller.class);
                i.putExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_INTENT, new Intent(con,
                        LocationReceiver.class));
                i.putExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_PROVIDER,
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                gps = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(con, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
                gps.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                        10 * 1000, pi);
                Log.d("Service: ",
                        "GPS Service started and scheduled with AlarmManager");
```

Here is the class I created myself (not the one from your demo, though similar):

```
public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        Location loc = (Location) b.get(LocationPoller.EXTRA_LOCATION);

        String msg;

        if (loc == null)
        {
            loc = (Location) b.get(LocationPoller.EXTRA_LASTKNOWN);

            if (loc == null)
            {
                msg = intent.getStringExtra(LocationPoller.EXTRA_ERROR);
            }
            else
            {
                msg = "TIMEOUT, lastKnown=" + loc.toString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            msg = loc.toString();
        }

        if (msg == null)
        {
            msg = "Invalid broadcast received!";
        }

        Log.d("GPS Broadcast: ", "Location: " + msg);
    }

}
```

Nothing's happening. I assume this because I'm not seeing any info in my logcat, at all. Plus the PollerThread (if that's the right term) keeps piling up when I look at the debug view, as if they're all waiting for something but not sending any broadcasts.

What am I doing wrong? Ascertaining location via Network shouldn't take much time should it? Even if that was the issue, I should have gotten SOME feedback..

Here are the entries in my manifest's application tag:

```
<receiver android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.LocationPoller" />
        <receiver android:name=".LocationReceiver" />
        <service android:name="com.commonsware.cwac.locpoll.LocationPollerService" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LocationPoller` is designed for much longer polling periods: an hour, not 10 seconds. I have never tested `LocationPoller` with that frequent of a polling period, nor do I ever intend to support `LocationPoller` with a polling period shorter than the `DEFAULT_TIMEOUT` of two minutes.

Hence, the first thing you should do is figure out why you are bothering with `LocationPoller` in the first place. The point behind `LocationPoller` is to be able to occasionally figure out where the device is, without your code necessarily already running (e.g., you want to automatically check into Foursquare every hour). If you need to find out where the device is every 10 seconds, you need to use `LocationManager` yourself from a foreground activity.

Assuming you are convinced that `LocationPoller` is still the right solution, the next thing you should do is extend your polling period to something more reasonable, like 5 minutes, and see if that helps.

If that does not help, then try running the `demo/` project without modification. If *that* does not work, then there's some bug in `LocationPoller`, or some incompatibility in your device that `LocationPoller` is tripping over, and I'd need to do some investigation.

If the `demo/` project *does* work, make a copy, confirm the copy works, and then slowly modify the copy to look more like what your production code has, until it stops working -- at that point, your last set of changes represent what broke `LocationPoller`, and we can figure out if that represents a bug in `LocationPoller` or a bug in your use of it.

Comment: I got some help from another guy here who basically imported files from your library directly into a project and used them. Its working fine now. I think the problem was with the receiver declaration in my manifest (something related to packages).

Now about your point... I'm getting a driver's location (it is being sent to the server where a desktop app is gonna display it on a map). I chose your code/library because well, you write excellent code! I'm new to Android development so I don't always know what to look for, what to avoid, what to handle etc.

I'm going to change the time to 40s.

Comment: Umm can you tell me what changes do I need to make in order to make your Service automatically choose the best Provider? My app will make the user enable GPS but suppose he isn't able to get a lock, I wanna be able to use the Network Provider too.

Comment: @Asim: You would need to modify `requestLocation()` on `LocationPollerService` (to allow `EXTRA_PROVIDER` to be either a `String` or a `Criteria`) and `onPreExecute()` on its `PollerThread` inner class (to use a different `requestLocationUpdates()` version that takes the `Criteria` instead of the provider name).

Comment: I'm getting an error after every update.. Its something like handler sending message to a dead thread. I'll post the exact message if needed. It doesn't break functionality but I'd like to know what's happening.

Comment: @Asim: If your error is reproducible using just the `demo/` app and an un-modified version of the library, please post an issue on the GitHub repo. If your error is reproducible with another test app and an un-modified version of the library, please post an issue, including the source code to the test app (e.g., link to a GitHub repo containing that code). If your error is unique to your modified version of the library, you are welcome to open a fresh SO question with the details, though getting help may be difficult.